# Can gcc on Ubuntu on a 64-bit machine generate an executable where long is 32-bits?

Tags: compiler-construction, 64-bit

In other words is compilation with data-model LLP64 possible in this environment? Please note that my pointers should be 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's possible (at least for AMD)

> -m32
>   -m64
>   Generate code for a 32-bit or 64-bit environment. The 32-bit
>   environment sets int, long and pointer
>   to 32 bits and generates code that
>   runs on any i386 system. The 64-bit
>   environment sets int to 32 bits and
>   long and pointer to 64 bits and
>   generates code for AMD's x86-64
>   architecture.

Comment: You mean "not possible".  That compiles in ILP32 or LP64 modes -- not LLP64.  In fact, I'm not convinced that GCC support LLP64 at all... even on arches where there exists a `-mlong32/-mlong64` switch, it still doesn't choose LLP64.

Comment: The original Q said could they have 32bit longs and 64bit pointers. Which my reading of this option seems possible

Comment: The original question did not explicitly state pointer size, but LLP64 means "64-bit long long and pointer".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `-m32`

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html#i386-and-x86_002d64-Options

EDIT: I wrote this answer before he mentioned pointers in the question. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857296/can-gcc-on-ubuntu-on-a-64-bit-machine-generate-an-executable-where-long-is-32-bit/1857614#1857614)

Comment: That compiles in ILP32 mode (32-bit int, long, pointer; 64-bit long long).  I would have guessed that OP wanted 64-bit pointers (otherwise why call it LLP64?)...

Comment: You are right, but since he didn't mention pointers at all, I believe he's just concerned about longs. In addition true LLP64 is not possible in Linux (to best of my knowledge, I can be wrong).

Comment: Actually ephemient is right, I was indeed looking for 32-bit long and 64-bit pointer like MS Windows 64-bit compiler works.

Comment: After compiling with -m32 my pointers became 4 bytes! Not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible on Linux. 
See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLP64#Specific_data_models) for details.